# iOS perform action whenever it comes back from Background or Suspended

Tags: ios

I am trying to show some screen for just 2 seconds once App becomes active from background or suspended mode..

So trying to use - (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application in App delegate class..

But since I am in App Delegate class, I am struggling to show the screen in two seconds..

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{


    SplashViewController *splashScreen = [[[SplashViewController alloc]    
                                       initWithNibName:@"SplashViewController"    
                                                      bundle:nil]autorelease];
```

and then what is the best way to use presentModalViewController or addSubview here for 2 seconds..

Comment: 2 seconds will seem awfully slow every time a user goes into your app. Splash screens are actively discouraged by Apple in the HIG.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Display the splash, then in the `viewDidAppear` method of your `SplashViewController`, trigger a timer to dismiss it, either with an `NSTimer` or using the much more simpler call of `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:`.